# Rendering encoded html on browser

Tags: html, browser, encoding

We are sending an html response like below from our server to the browser (It contains a lot of java script etc but keeping it simpler here for the question)

```
&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;b&gt;Hello&lt;&#x2f;b&gt;&lt;&#x2f;body&gt;&lt;&#x2f;html&gt;&#xd;&#xa;
```

but the browser instead of rendering an html page shows string containing following

```
<html><body><b>Hello</b></body></html>
```

Browser output required is

**Hello**

How do we make sure that the browser instead of showing the html as a string actually renders it on the page?

Comment: "spaces put here so that they are rendered as sent by our server" — There is a *code* button in the GUI for the Stackoverflow editor. Please use it instead of adding extra spaces to you code to show how the code doesn't actually look.

Comment: I don't understand the question anyway. The response isn't a valid HTML document, but it is being rendered the way I would expect it to be rendered (at least as far as I can tell, you aren't communicating what you input, output or expected output is very well).

Comment: Thanks @Quentin, I have edited the question. Ok the thing is the browser shows the html text instead of rendering the html. So for example If I send a lot of html and js functions information encoded  like this from the server, the idea is that browser instead of showing that data should render an HTML page.

Comment: The browser is showing an HTML page. You are sending the HTML code to render `<html></html>`. It sounds like you want it to render it as plain text instead of HTML.

Comment: @Quentin, well yes. Somewhat, I have further updated the question to make more sense, Realized it was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, the `<` character means "Start a tag" but you are using `&lt;` which means "Display a less than character".

You have similar issues with `>` and `/`.

Use the characters with special meaning in HTML. Don't encode them as character references.

Comment: Thanks, The thing is we have to send the response encoded as mentioned but want the browser to understand that it is an HTML to be rendered and not a string to be displayed. Updated with an example in the question.

Comment: You need to address the real problem (which is whatever is making you encode HTML you don't want the browser to treat as encoded). You can't make the browser handle it differently.